# what is 'UnimplementedFeatureError: Not yet implemented - FixedPointType' error?

Tags: solidity, truffle, solc, truffle-compile, solidity-0.5.x

what is '**UnimplementedFeatureError: Not yet implemented - FixedPointType**' error in solidity while compiling through truffle ?

How to fix it ?

Using solidity compiler version - 0.5.9

Answer (score 0):

From the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.9/types.html#fixed-point-numbers):

> Fixed point numbers are not fully supported by Solidity yet. They can be declared, but cannot be assigned to or from.

The only possible fix at this point is to not use fixed point numbers.

Comment: but i am not using it

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the contract source code?