# Why doesn't the solidity perform rounding off to nearest whole number

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging, uint256, floating-point

The function getInt() is always returning more than 1. Shouldn't it do a round off for values less than 0.5 and return 0 ? Please check the image[image: test function] and let me know, if I am doing something incorrectly or if there is a way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to run this code on remix it gave `UnimplementedFeatureError: Not yet implemented - FixedPointType.` Which you can see [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76534/what-is-unimplementedfeatureerror-not-yet-implemented-fixedpointtype-error)
This is not possible to use `uint(3/30)` as you are doing. Casting of any floating point using uint is not acceptable.

The Fixed Point are not yet unuseable in solidity as it documentation says:

> Fixed point numbers are not fully supported by Solidity yet. They can
>   be declared, but cannot be assigned to or from.

**You may solve this problem by.**

1)You may use divi function from [ABDK Math 64.64 library](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.sol#L219). It divides one integer by another and returns the result as 64.64-bit fixed point number.

2)You can multiply the number by `10^n`. Where '**n**' is number of decimals in your return value.

```
((3/30)*3)*100
```

**EDIT:**

> I want to understand - why does my test1 function doesn't return 0 but
>   returns 1

Well the uint shouldn't return anything at all instead it must give an error as mentioned above.

Comment: Haseeb, You mention - Division on integer literals used to truncate in earlier versions, but it will now convert into a rational number, i.e. 5 / 2 is not equal to 2, but to 2.5 : But that's not correct. Also, i want to understand - why does my test1 function not return 0 but returns 1.

Comment: @rajatBlock hope you like my answer

Comment: Thanks.I suppose there is an issue with REMIX - it allowed me to deploy the contract with the compilation warning. And, also what it does is - gives the last correct answer before the number became floating point. Anyways, all this aside - I think still point no. 2 in your "You may solve this problem by section." still does not help me deal with the actual problem - which is how to return 0 for numbers less than 0.5. Rather the answer from your edit - that it gives the compilation error, is correct and cannot be actually deployed.